# Reading database properties from property source not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, properties

I want to read my database property values from the application.property file but not being able to.

I tried reading the properties from custom properties file but it didnt work. I don't want to hard code the properties as it will will be different in different servers.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class DatabaseUtils {

    @Value("${mysql.drive}")
    private static String MY_SQL_DRIVER;

    @Value("${mysql.url}")
    private static String MY_SQL_URL;

    @Value("${mysql.username}")
    private static String DATABASE_USERNAME;

    @Value("${mysql.password}")
    private static String DATABASE_PASSWORD;

    public DatabaseUtils () {

    }

    @Bean
     public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
      return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
     }

    public static ResultSet executeDBQuery(String query) {
        try {

            Class.forName(MY_SQL_DRIVER);
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(MY_SQL_URL, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            return resultSet;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}


(properties file)
# database
databaseDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
databaseUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school
databaseUsername=root
databasePassword=root

I am new to spring-boot so getting a little confused as to why its not working, read a lot of online sources and tried them but didnt work, not sure what I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.
```

Comment: @PropertySource("application.properties") is not required. and you are giving wrong placeholder to @Value

Comment: @rakcity is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

The properties in your property file is different from what you are giving in @Value.for eg. your property key is databaseDriver but you are giving mysql.drive in your code.

```
 @Value("${mysql.drive}")
 private static String MY_SQL_DRIVER;
```

But it should be

```
@Value("${databaseDriver}")
 private static String MY_SQL_DRIVER;
```

Answer (score 0):

basically what properties you define in the properties file should be referred in the application right. Here you are defining property as databaseDriver.

```
   databaseDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Then in code also you should ask for "databaseDriver"

```
 @Value("${databaseDriver}")
  private static String MY_SQL_DRIVER;
```